# Prove that $(1+p)^{p^{v-2}} \equiv 1+p^{v-1} \mod p^v$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be an odd prime, $v\geq 2$. Prove
$$(1+p)^{p^{v-2}} \equiv 1+p^{v-1} \mod p^v$$

I thought about using induction. For $v=2$ it's pretty trivial.

From induction step $v-1 \rightarrow v$ we have

$$(1+p)^{p^{v-3}}\equiv 1+p^{v-2}\mod p^{v-1} \Rightarrow (1+p)^{p^{v-3}}\equiv 1+p^{v-2}\mod p^v$$
Then
$$(1+p)^{p^{v-2}}=((1+p)^{p^{v-3}})^p\equiv (1+p^{v-2})^{p}\mod p^v$$

I'm not sure how to proceed further. I've tried similar approaches with the Binomial Theorem but no success so far.

I'd be really glad if someone has a good tip for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write out $(1 + p^{v - 2})^p$ using binomial theorem:
$$(1 + p^{v - 2})^p = 1 + p\cdot p^{v - 2} + \binom p 2 \cdot p^{2(v - 2)} + \dots$$ and notice that for $v \geq 3$, starting from the third term, every term is a multiple of $p\cdot p^{2(v - 2)}$ and hence a multiple of $p^v$.

Comment: I haven't looked at this detail, but I have noticed that $(1 + p^{v - 2})^p$, which you wrote, looks different from $(1+p)^{p^{v-2}}$, which OP wrote

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I continued the proof of the OP, i.e. from $(1 + p)^{p^{v - 2}} \equiv (1 + p^{v - 2})^p\mod p^v$.

Comment: I see now.  As I (meant to) say, I hadn’t looked at it in detail

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very clear except for one little detail. You said for $v\geq 3$ every term starting at 3rd term is a multiple of $p\cdot p^{2(v-2)}$. So in other words I can extract $p$ from $\binom{p}{k}$ and what remains is still an integer. Is that because binomial coefficients of primes are always divisible by the prime? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, you can extract $p$ from the binomial coefficient for every term except the very last, i.e. the term $p^{p(v-2)}$. However since $p>2$ and $v>2$, this term is also divisible by $p\cdot p^{2(v-2)}$. To see that the other binomial coefficients are divisible by $p$, use the identity $k\binom p k=p\binom{p-1}{k-1}$ and the fact that $p$ is prime to $k$.